# Why am I not able to update my text file?

Tags: c++, file, io

I'm making an inventory system, and I am using two text files, one to store the details, the other to store updated details temporarily.

I want to update the information in `updatedinventory.txt` to `inventory.txt`. For example, if I update the number of products of `p1` from 2 to 20, then I want to make those changes to `inventory.txt` and not to `updateinventory.txt`.

Here is what I have so far:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string product_name;
    int product_price, product_num;

    cout<< "enter the product name: ";
    cin>> product_name;

    ifstream infile("inventory.txt", std::ios_base::app);
    ofstream outfile("updatedinventory.txt" );

    string storedproductname;

    while(infile >> storedproductname >> product_num >> product_price) 
    {   
        if (storedproductname == product_name){
            
            cout << "product exist already...update number of products: ";
            cin >> product_num;
            outfile << storedproductname << ' ' << product_num << ' ' << product_price << endl;
            cout << "details updated...";
            return 0;
        }
        //else {outfile << storedproductname << ' ' << product_num << ' ' << product_price << endl;}  
        } 
            cout<< "enter the number of products: ";
            cin>> product_num;

            cout << "enter the price of 1 product: ";
            cin>> product_price;
            cout<< "product added...";

            outfile << product_name << ' ' << product_num << ' ' << product_price << endl; 

    infile.close();
    outfile.close();

    remove("inventory.txt");
    rename("updatedinventory.txt","inventory.txt");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is it doing differently than what you expect? And why are you opening an input file in append mode?

Comment: Under `if (storedproductname == product_name){` you do `return 0`. `main` function exits, the program terminates, and `remove/rename` dance is never done.

Comment: *"i'm making this inventory system"* -- This seems rather unnecessary for your question. Think abstractly; don't be so tied to your current project. Go with something simple to demonstrate your issue, such as starting with `inventory.txt` containing `2` (just the one number) and showing just the code relevant to updating this to `14` (not `20` so that it's not a simple append). Then add an explanation at the end that this is simplified from an inventory system to head off questions about why you are doing this.

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to be a working version of your code (but I haven't tested anything).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string product_name;
    int product_price, product_num;

    cout<< "enter the product name: ";
    cin>> product_name;

    ifstream infile("inventory.txt");
    ofstream outfile("updatedinventory.txt");

    string storedproductname;

    while(infile >> storedproductname >> product_num >> product_price) 
    {   
        if (storedproductname == product_name){
            
            cout << "product exist already...update number of products: ";
            cin >> product_num;
            outfile << storedproductname << ' ' << product_num << ' ' << product_price << endl;
            cout << "details updated...";
        }
        else {
            outfile << storedproductname << ' ' << product_num << ' ' << product_price << endl;
        }
            
    } 

    infile.close();
    outfile.close();

    remove("inventory.txt");
    rename("updatedinventory.txt","inventory.txt");

    return 0;
}
```

Seems like you had the basic idea correct, i.e. read the whole file and output each line unchanged except the one that you want to change. However you were not paying attention to the details, `ios_base::app` was incorrect, `return 0;` was incorrect, and the correct else clause had been commented out for some reason. Details are very important in programming.